# Parallel processing of python code

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm dealing with a code of mine. The code is taking really long to complete on single cpu.
So, I was thinking if it is possible to make the code go for parallel processing.
The code frame is like:

```
def analyze_data(target_path):
   import os
   import math
   import itertools
   import numpy
   import scipy 
   ....
   for files in target_path:
      <a real long series of calculations......
      ...................>

   return
#Providing the dir search path:
dir_path = "/usr/target_dir/"
analyze_data(target_path=dir_path)
```

This code is taking way way long to finish(obviously number of files to process is huge).
Now is there a way I can execute this simple coding-format in multiprocessing threads to get it run faster ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation (for python3): https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html

If you can split your directories to be process:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def analyze_data(target_path):
   import os
   import math
   import itertools
   import numpy
   import scipy 
   ....
   for files in target_path:
      <a real long series of calculations......
      ...................>

   return
#Providing the dir search path:

analyze_data(target_path=dir_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        dir_path1 = "/usr/target_dir/1"
        dir_path2 = "/usr/target_dir/2"
        dir_path3 = "/usr/target_dir/3"
        print(p.map(analyze_data, [dir_path1, dir_path2, dir_path3]))
```

Comment: still 'm not getting... 'coz each file(a dir has 40/50 of those files) takes about 2hr to complete. So I'm searching for an effective way to counter this issue...

Comment: `print(p.map(analyze_data, [dir_path1, dir_path2, dir_path3]))` Is this line passing each directory to a single thread ? I may need to distribute each file to multiple thread to make it faster.

Comment: I am pretty sure the line distrbute the command to multi-process, but an experience python user may confirme that.

Comment: Is it directing each directory to multiprocessing or each file inside dir to multiprocessing ? 'm not trained in multiprocessing earlier, so asked.

Answer (score 0):

By using a fork of `multiprocessing` called `pathos.multiprocessing`, this can be really easy… and can be done quite naturally from the interpreter.  I will also leverage `pox`, which has some filesystem utilities that are in addition to those in the `os` and `sys` modules. Let's first check out the test files that I've set up.  There are several files in each directory.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.abspath('.')
'/tmp'
>>> import pox
>>> # find all the .txt files in and below the current directory
>>> pox.find('*.txt', '.')
['/tmp/xxx/1.txt', 'tmp/xxx/2.txt', 'tmp/xxx/3.txt', 'tmp/yyy/1.txt', 'tmp/yyy/2.txt', 'tmp/zzz/1.txt', 'tmp/zzz/2.txt', 'tmp/zzz/3.txt', 'tmp/zzz/4.txt']
>>> # let's look at the contents of one of the files
>>> print open('xxx/1.txt', 'r').read()
45125123412
12341234123
12342134234
23421342134
```

All the files have similar contents… so let's get to work processing the files in parallel.

```
>>> import time
>>> import pathos
>>> # build a thread pool of workers
>>> thPool = pathos.multiprocessing.ThreadingPool 
>>> tp = thPool()
>>> 
>>> # expensive per-file processing
>>> def doit(file):
...     with open(file, 'r') as f:
...         x = sum(int(i) for i in f.readlines())
...     time.sleep(1) # make it 'expensive'
...     return len(str(x))**2  # some calculation
... 
>>> # grab all files from a directory, then do some final 'analysis'
>>> def analyze_data(target_path):
...     return min(*tp.uimap(doit, pox.find('*.txt', target_path)))
... 
>>> analyze_data('.')
121
```

Actually, the `analyze_data` is somewhat irrelevant, as `find` doesn't need to work on a per-directory basis… but that's the structure specified in the question.  Here, you'd replace the majority of `doit` with the expensive per-file tasks, and would replace `min` with the per-directory processing.  Depending on how expensive the calculation is, you might want to use `pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessingPool` instead of the `ThreadingPool` -- the former will spawn multiple processes, while the latter just spawns multiple threads.  The former has more overhead, but can handle more expensive tasks in parallel better.  Here, we use `uimap` to provide an unordered iterator over calling `doit` on each file.

Get `pathos` and `pox` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation